# ElasticSearch JSON expectations

Tags: json, csv, elasticsearch

I'm in need of a basic definition and usage expectation for ElasticSearch.
I have an ever growing folder of CSV-delimited based data (in files).

Elasticsearch likes JSON. I get that, and I have the ability to convert them over with no issue.

What I need to know is this:  does each CSV row need to be in it's own file.json file to be considered for indexing?  is that what a document is? or do I bulk stack JSON entries into a single file and run them in for indexing?  is the json entry a document? or the file.json a document as ElasticSearch sees it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, each CSV row is considered a document once turned into JSON. Now, you have a few options.

A. You can keep your CSV file as it is and [use Logstash to consume it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43701016/import-csv-into-elasticsearch/43702910#43702910) using a `csv` filter and send the resulting JSON documents to Elasticsearch.

B. You can transform your CSV file in another file, where each CSV row is turned into a one-liner JSON document, i.e.

Instead of

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
Cell11,Cell12,Cell13
Cell21,Cell22,Cell23
```

You have

```
{ "Col1": "Cell11", "Col2": "Cell12", "Col3": "Cell13" }
{ "Col1": "Cell21", "Col2": "Cell22", "Col3": "Cell23" }
```

But you'd still need to use [Logstash in order to load that multi-JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868921/parsing-json-file-into-logstash/33885647#33885647) into Elasticsearch

C. A last option is to transform the CSV file into a so-called [bulk file](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) that would look like this:

```
{ "index": {}}
{ "Col1": "Cell11", "Col2": "Cell12", "Col3": "Cell13" }
{ "index": {}}
{ "Col1": "Cell21", "Col2": "Cell22", "Col3": "Cell23" }
```

And then you can load that file using a single command via the [Bulk API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32863112/elasticsearch-bulk-index-api-via-rest-endpoint/32864366#32864366).

Comment: Thanks VAL...this makes sense.  sometimes the assumption of knowledge can kill alot of things.  Good stuff. Thanks!